# Vim Taglist: How to jump to a tag definition from within an open source file

Tags: vim, taglist

I wonder what Vim [Taglist](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) is good for if I cannot jump to a tags definition from within an open source file. Do I have to generate a separate tags file by running, say, `ctags *.f90`, in order to be able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need a *tags database* (usually created by running `ctags` or an equivalent external tool) to use the tag jump / search functionality of Vim.

As Vim is a general-purpose text editor, it does not possess any knowledge about individual languages, and instead delegates (in true spirit of Unix's *do one thing well* mantra) this to an external resource.

PS: There are plugins like [easytags.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3114) that automate the process of tags generation and update.

Comment: Thank you. Thus, taglist is just an addition to the still required `:!ctags *' invocation (either manual or automated via easytags)? The actual purpose of taglist remains unclear to me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _taglist_? The :tag... commands, or the taglist plugin (which ought to invoke ctags automatically)?!

Comment: Indeed, vim-taglist invokes ctags, but doesn't keep the tags file which is necessary for Control+] to work.

Comment: Yep, you've got it now! romainl also spelled this out in detail in his good answer.

Comment: Thanks once more, in particular for the easytags pointer. I will be using them both, vim-taglist and easytags.

Answer (score 4):

What is this `taglist` you are talking about?

The only `taglist` I know of are:

- the `taglist()` function (`:h taglist()`), which is of no use for you (or me) in your daily Vim usage,
- and the [TagList](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) plugin.

Do you refer to the `:tag` family of commands?

`<C-]>` and `:tag` are used in conjunction with a `tags` file to jump to the declaration of a variable or method or whatever. If you have no `tags` file, `<C-]>` simply won't work.

The TagList plugin, uses `ctags` under the hood to build an actionable list of the elements present in your file(s) but it doesn't use a `tags` file: the result of the `ctags` command is consumed directly.

That means that you can perfectly have a working TagList plugin and a non-working `<C-]>` (and `:tag`, `:tselect`, etc…) at the same time. Those are separate features.